# Find a specifc element with jquery to toggle

Tags: jquery, find, toggle

i have this structure (it reapeats three times)

```
<div class="main">                   //  onlick toggle class sub
    <img>
    <div></div>
</div>

<div class="sub">                  
   <span>Toggle</span>               // onlick toggle class sub
</div>
```

now i  have this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.main').click(function(){
        $('.sub').slideToggle(2000);
    });
});
```

because i have this three times, with my code i have to repeat the code with differnt classes, because only on sub should be visible.

i need something like this

```
onlick THIS_ELEMENT toggle the next SUB class Element AND if a sub class is allready open close it and open this sub class
```

and for the toggle button in the sub class, something like this:

```
onlick THIS_ELEMENT close this SUB class element
```

you know how to do this ?

Comment: please share jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking us to select(toggle) the element which is the immediate next sibling of the current element. So in that context, just use `.next()` to grab the target element.

Try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.main').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.sub').slideToggle(2000);
  }); 
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/34QWb/)

Comment: that works great, but what do i have to do with the trigger in the sub element ? it doenst work

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers' `this` reference the element to which the event is fired. (Note that this is true **only** when using jQuery or similar frameworks).

So in your example use:

```
$(this).next('.sub').slide(...)
```

in your event handler.